# Function precondition not accepting a verification whether map contains key

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to define a function that receives a pair of x-y coordinates and a direction which a robot is facing (*:north*, *:east*, *:south* and *:west*).

I defined a map called *directions* which holds the valid values (and which will be used later for movement).

```
(def directions {:north {:x 0 :y 1} :east {:x 1 :y 0} :south {:x 0 :y -1} :west {:x -1 :y 0}})
```

And for validation purposes, I created a *:pre* clause to prevent invalid values for such parameters:

```
(defn create-robot 
  "Creates a Robot representation, containing its position (x,y) and directions which it is facing"
  [x y direction]
  {:pre [(int? x) (>= x 0)
         (int? y) (>= y 0)
         (contains? directions direction)]}
  (Robot. x y direction))
```

Now, here's the problem: when I run my test, it fails because of this *contains?* validation. The thing is, I'm using a valid value for my test, still, it is failing.

```
(let [robot (create-robot 1 2 :north)]
  (expect 1 (:x robot))
  (expect 2 (:y robot))
  (expect :north (:direction robot)))
```

It gives me the following error:

```
Error refreshing environment: java.lang.AssertionError: Assert failed: (contains? directions direction)
```

Would someone be able to tell me what is wrong? Am I expecting too much from preconditions?

Thanks and Cheers.

#### Update

As required by @Alan Thompson, I added a *println*

```
(defn create-robot 
  "Creates a Robot representation, containing its position (x,y) and directions which it is facing"
  [x y direction]
  {:pre [(int? x) (>= x 0)
         (int? y) (>= y 0) 
         (or (println direction) true)
         (or (println (directions direction)) true)
         (or (println (str "Contains? " (contains? directions direction))) true)
         (contains? directions direction)]}
  (Robot. x y direction))
```

And the result shows as expected (except that this time the test passes):

```
*************** Running tests ***************
:reloading (jaegers.domain jaegers.core jaegers.core-test)
:north
{:x 0, :y 1}
Contains? true
:north
{:x 0, :y 1}
Contains? true

Ran 18 tests containing 18 assertions in 5 msecs
0 failures, 0 errors.
Tests completed at 19:17:38.593
```

I don't understand how it works now.

Comment: What is the `expect` you are using?  Also, adding some `println` statements will greatly clarify the input values.

Comment: I'm using expectations (https://clojure-expectations.github.io/).
Basically, the test only certifies that a record is created with the correct data (x y and direction). I'll add some printlns. But I'm not sure if it has the time to evaluate any instruction, since it probably throws AssertionError before even enters the function.

Comment: That could have been due to an IDE issue. If you remove the prints, does it continue to work?

Comment: Also note, you can just write `(directions direction)` instead of `contains?`.

Comment: Well @AlanThompson, not sure if it's an IDE issue. Probably not, because I'm using VSCode and running the tests on console. But the only thing that matters is that is working now. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Carcigenicate, you're right. Much better that way.

Comment: Definitely should work. I used `(contains? #{:north :east :south :west} bearing)` in [this bot](https://github.com/dtonhofer/joy_of_clojure_notes/blob/master/Chapter%207%20-%20Functional%20programming/standard_bot.clj) some time ago.

Answer (score 1):

I never use the `expectations` lib.  Instead, I like a slightly more convenient version of `clojure.test`.  Here is your code, which works as expected:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test) )

(defrecord Robot [x y direction])

(def directions {:north {:x 0 :y 1}
                 :east {:x 1 :y 0}
                 :south {:x 0 :y -1}
                 :west {:x -1 :y 0}})

(defn create-robot
  "Creates a Robot representation, containing its position (x,y) and directions which it is facing"
  [x y direction]
  {:pre [(int? x) (>= x 0)
         (int? y) (>= y 0)
         (contains? directions direction)]}
  (Robot. x y direction))

; Now, here's the problem: when I run my test, it fails because of this contains? validation. The thing is, I'm using a valid value for my test, still, it is failing.
(dotest
  (let [robot (create-robot 1 2 :north)]
    (is= 1 (spyx (:x robot)))
    (is= 2 (spyx (:y robot)))
    (is= :north (spyx (:direction robot)))))
```

The `spyx` just prints to the console to verify visually what is happening:

```
-----------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.1    Java 12.0.1
-----------------------------------

Testing tst.demo.core
(:x robot) => 1
(:y robot) => 2
(:direction robot) => :north

Ran 2 tests containing 3 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.

Passed all tests
Finished at 16:52:59.262 (run time: 0.054s)
```

Not sure what went wrong with your first attempt.  Try it again or try my version to get more info.

Also, you never said what the `Robot` class does.  Is that a Java class?  If so, it could be related.

Comment: Not sure o what was causing the issue.
Maybe there was another subtle issue I accidentally corrected while putting those printlns and didn't notice.
Robot is a record such the one you did on your version.